# Why does TypeScript infer this strange type for the value of a computed property?

Tags: typescript

During my first go at writing this function, I encountered some unexpected behaviour:

```
function splatIfDefinedBad<K extends string, V>(
    key: K,
    value: V
): Partial<Record<K, V>> {
    if (value === undefined) {
        return {}
    }
    return { [key] : value }
}
```

The TypeScript compiler emits the error:

> Type '{ [x: string]: V & ({} | null); }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Record<K, V>>'.

I could't figure out where the `& ({} | null)` part of the type inferred for `value` was coming from.

Changing the way I construct the object rectifies the problem:

```
function splatIfDefinedGood<K extends string, V>(
    key: K,
    value: V
): Partial<Record<K, V>> {
    if (value === undefined) {
        return {}
    }
    const output: Partial<Record<K, V>> = {};
    output[key] = value;
    return output;
}
```

At first, this implied to me that something about how computed properties work makes it possible for `{ [key]: value }` to produce `{ [key]: null }` even when the type V doesn't contain the value `null`.

Then I noticed that `{} | null` means "anything except `undefined`" (since the type `{}` means "anything except `null` or `undefined`"), so I'm guessing this has something to do with how TypeScript type inference operates? It's trying to narrow V down to exclude `undefined` but tripping up when it gets `V & Not<undefined>` (imagining that that mapped type existed) because it can't unify properly? Whereas with the `splatIfDefinedGood` version, it's going in the reverse direction, adding a property of `V` at `K` on a type it already understands, rather than trying to narrow down from "anything" to "anything but undefined"?

**EDIT**:

As @ruakh points out, the problem is just in `K` being broadened to `string`! The following works fine:

```
function splatIfDefined2<K extends string, V>(
    key: K,
    value: V
): Partial<Record<K, V>> {
    if (value === undefined) {
        return {}
    }
    return { [key as K] : value } as { [k in K]: V & ({} | null) }
}
```

Comment: I'm no TypeScript expert, but the `V & ({} | null)` part actually seems fine to me, since that's *more* restrictive than `V`. Rather, the problem seems to be on the `[x: string]` part: TypeScript is upcasting your `key` from `K` to `string`, but you need it to still be `K`.

Comment: OK, yes, what I wrote above is correct; [it happily does the assignment if the desired key-type is `string` instead of `K`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwA4BsCGUCSwAiApsDGIQCYDqMUAFgMpQBOpA5gDwDSihAHlITDlkKZmwA0iAGoA+ABQAoRMsQBrQgE8AXIk7ilKgG6Z0IQjqkKAlDoAKmJrBPsASoQhwm5dsjFhWkrIyiADeBsowwIhyxqaEiAC8SYjg5MSkFFah4SrKTIRQIExIIQC+OeW5+YXFoQDa6hoAujqxZuWlQA).

Comment: More "values" can be assigned = less restrictive, not more restrictive

Comment: Have you tried giving `value` the type `NonNullable<V>|null`?

Comment: I only seem to find things that point out that typescript only likes `string|number|Symbol` as a computed property key types

Comment: Actually, for any type `T`, fewer or the same number of values can be assigned to `T & ({} | null)`, because `&` can only lower the number of assignable values.

Comment: Distributivity of types gives `(T & {}) | (T & null)` which you is then simplified as (keeping ltr order) `T|null`. Ergo, no

Comment: `let a: undefined | null | {} = undefined;` is fine but `let b: (typeof a) & ({} | null) = undefined;` throws a type error

Comment: The only intersection between any `T` and `null` is `null|never`.

Comment: I'm curious about this distributivity of types. Looking through the Google results, I can only find this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types which appears to only apply in "conditional types in which the checked type is a naked type parameter".

Comment: @PoolOfPeas: Vivick is actually correct that `T & ({} | null)` is equivalent to `(T & {}) | (T & null)`; where (s)he's going wrong is in his/her attempts to simplify the latter. "Distributivity of types" may not be perfect phrasing, but (s)he's referring to the type-theoretic equivalent of https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Intersection_Distributes_over_Union.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually deeply confused about this.

My intuition is that intersecting a set A with another set cannot produce a set larger than A, so that there's no way to get `null` into T if it wasn't already there. I'm struggling to reconcile that with the algebraic manipulation. I know that if T already contains null, then (T & null) constains null, but if T doesn't contain null, then (T & null) is the empty set.

Comment: However, when I work through it, I get the same answer as Vivick did.                     T & ({} | null) -> (T & {}) | (T & null) -> (T & {}) | (null | never) -> Exclude<T, undefined | null> | (null | never) -> Exclude<T, undefined | null> | null -> Exclude<T, undefined> | null.                                   I think what I'm trying to express is: (T & {}) | (null | never) -> Exclude<T, undefined | null> | (null extends T ? null : never) -> Exclude<T, undefined>. Is there something fundamentally different because T isn't a concrete set, but a "space" of possible sets?

Comment: I suppose this question is primarily about widening of the key to `string`, which is the subject of [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948); see the linked q/a for more info.  The stuff with `& ({} | null)` is just how `NonNullable` works since [TS4.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-8.html#improved-intersection-reduction-union-compatibility-and-narrowing).

Comment: Strange to see TS choose to fix a bug in the language by introducing a hacky "fix". My simplification is right based on the type and boolean arithmetic equivalence demonstrated by Alonzo Church (or was it Haskell Curry?). A type system that doesn't have such fundamental properties will be clunky to use

Comment: @PoolOfPeas: If you want me to see your comments, please tag me with `@ruakh`. As for where your simplification is going awry . . . the problem is that you're trying to simultaneously consider the case where T includes null and the case where T excludes null, and are getting confused in the process. Just separate them: *Case 1.* If T includes null, then `(T & {}) | (T & null)` simplifies to `(T & {}) | null`, which is not less restrictive than T (since T includes null to begin with). *Case 2.* If T excludes null, then  `(T & {}) | (T & null)` simplifies to `(T & {}) | never`, i.e. `T & {}`.

Comment: @Vivick: Please see my last comment to PoolOfPeas.

Answer (score 2):

As @ruakh pointed out in a comment, the problem is just in K being broadened to string! The following works fine:

```
function splatIfDefined2<K extends string, V>(
    key: K,
    value: V
): Partial<Record<K, V>> {
    if (value === undefined) {
        return {}
    }
    return { [key as K] : value } as { [k in K]: V & ({} | null) }
}
```

indicating that `V & ({} | null)` is indeed assignable to `V`.